# Display ng-grid with nested array of JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, ng-grid

I have some JSON data that looks like so:

```
return {
    "activityTypes" :[{
        "id" :"",
        "name:" :"",
        "icon" : "",
        "partial": "",
        "label" : {
            "id": "",
            "name": ""
        }
    }],
    "apiKey" : "",
    "approveBy": 0,
    "approvers" : [], 
    "canSendTo" : [{
        "id" : "",
        "name" : ""
    }],  
    "creators" : [],
    "isActive" : false,
    "notification" : false, 
    "sourceId": "",
    "sourceName":""
};
```

I am trying to use ng-grid, but I am trouble trying to access the elements inside an array of objects, such as the `activityTypes` or `canSendTo` arrays. In the following example, I tried to display canSendTo's id. I've tried the following but it does not render on the screen. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

```
{field: 'canSendTo.id', displayName: 'Can Send To', width:'10%',
    cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText", style="white-space: normal;">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>'},
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about ng-grid, but from a straight javascript perspective it should be canSendTo[0].id, since canSendTo is a one element array.

Comment: Hm, I tried your method but unfortunately nothing is displaying. When I use field: 'canSendTo', in every field I get every object (all the contents within it  and it looks like [{id: "blah", name: "blah2"}], but I can't seem to get any element within that object (I can't get or display the "blah" field in id by itself).